# update Chrome JRe

Tags: java, google-chrome, applet

after reading "Google chrome custom JRE/JDK/plugin" I decide to post because I do not get the desired behaviour.

OS : Windows 7 64 Bits.
Browser : Chrome version 20

I want Chrome to use C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\plugin2\npjp2.dll (that is the 64 Bits java plugin).

I launch regedit and go to the wow6432Node/Mozilla ... and change the path attribute of the @java.com/JavaPlugin node to my npjp2.

I quit chrome and restart : Chrome tells me that Java is not installed.

If I put back the previous version C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_10\jre\bin\new_plugin\npjp2.dll, Chrome tells me that my version is obsolete.

This proves that I Hack at the correct place but I cannot make it take the JVM 64 Bits.

After googling some more, I found this http://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp#win and this piece of info is interesting :

We have detected you may be viewing this page in a 32-bit browser. If you use 32-bit and 64-bit browsers interchangeably, you will need to install both 32-bit and 64-bit Java in order to have the Java plug-in for both browsers.

Which means That I need to install the 32Bits version of the JRE just to make Chrome happy:)

I leave the post for future googlers :)

Any ideas ?

Comment: You can answer your own question if you've worked it out.

Comment: this page is interesting :
http://www.chromium.org/nativeclient/design-documents/native-client-in-chrome-on-64-bit-windows

Answer (score 0):

I think only Internet Explorer can use 64-bit Java, other browsers can only work with 32-bit Java.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to go is to consider Chrome a 32bits app and give it a 32 bits JVM, and so even on a 64 bits Windows OS.

Interestingly, on MAC OS X Snow Leopard latest updates, no issues whatsoever : it works like a charm with the native jvms. I wonder what would happen if I played with the default jvms also...